Image not Rendering
I am new to blender, and I am trying to render a photorealistic soda can using cycles but when I hit the render image button unlike my other projects it just stays blank. 
Here are my cycles settings




Stays blank for how long? How long have you waited?

Note: The flagged duplicate contains some possibilities that, unless you turned Film -> Transparent on, I know are not the case here. what we are seeing is a solid transparent image.

Side note, you have the bar incredibly low for Noise Threshold with it set to a whopping 0.5 out of 1. You don't wanna do that, just use the defaults for starters.

What version of Blender are you using?

@TheLabCat He's using 3.6.11 according to the last two images in his question! :^)

@JohnEason You’re good at this. I forgot the version number was over there.
